# Looping a function over different sheets in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

so I have function lets call that XXXX . That function works over the course of one sheet only, trying to get it to work over all sheets as long as the sheet's name isn't "YYYY" or the sheet name doesn't include "ZZZZ" . What I have below runs our function (XXXX) on the first sheet then activates the last without running it over the sheets between the first and the last. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 function run_XXXX_for_all_tabs(){
 
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var allSheets =spreadsheet.getSheets();

  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "YYYY" && sheet.getSheetName().search("ZZZZ") < 0){
      sheet.activate();
      XXXX();
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getSheets()
                  .filter(i => i.getName() !== `YYYY` && !i.getName().includes(`ZZZZ`))
                  .forEach(i => {
                    i.activate()
                    XXXX()
                  })

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It still does the same thing where it runs XXXX for the first sheet (currently active) then activates the last sheet without running XXXX for the 2nd nor the 3rd sheet.

Comment: That would be a name issue then I'm guessing. It doesn't necessarily have to do with the order of the sheets.

Comment: If you have a reasonable amount of sheets, can you post their names and what you're actually trying to filter out?

Comment: I want it to work regardless of the sheet name , as long as its not "YYYY" and it doesn't include "ZZZZ" I currently have 4 sheets in my current test worksheet the first one is "YYYY" 2nd 3rd and 4th are all generic names (Sheet 1 , Sheet 2, Copy of sheet 1) Really appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: It worked on my spreadsheet with the same sheet names (YYYY, generic 1 - 3 with 3 being "Sheet 3ZZZZ")

Comment: Is there any conditional in XXXX() that could be effecting this?

Comment: Updated with pictures, let me know if you need anymore help!

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, I had few variables defined outside XXXX() which is why it was confused. It all works now, thanks NEWAZA. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Would you mind marking this as solved? If you have any other questions feel free to ask!